# Unrecognized option '-plugin' for /usr/bin/ld under MinGW

Tags: build, mingw, ld, gfortran, lapack

I am trying to compile LAPACK on Windows using MinGW/Msys.

When I run the command

```
$ make lapacklib
```

I obtain the following error:

```
$ make lapacklib
( cd INSTALL; make; ./testlsame; ./testslamch; ./testdlamch
        ./testsecond; ./testdsecnd; ./testieee; ./testversi
make[1]: Entering directory `/c/lapack-3.5.0/INSTALL'
gfortran  -O2 -frecursive -c lsame.f -o lsame.o
gfortran  -O2 -frecursive -c lsametst.f -o lsametst.o
gfortran  -o testlsame lsame.o lsametst.o
/usr/bin/ld: unrecognized option '-plugin'
/usr/bin/ld: use the --help option for usage information
collect2.exe: erreur: ld a retourné 1 code d'état d'exécuti
make[1]: *** [testlsame] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/lapack-3.5.0/INSTALL'
/bin/sh: ./testlsame: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: ./testslamch: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: ./testdlamch: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: line 1: ./testsecond: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: line 1: ./testdsecnd: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: line 1: ./testieee: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: line 1: ./testversion: No such file or directory
```

Where could be the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post `make.inc` file?

Comment: Thanks for replying @ctheo. Here it is https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxjyIIc9msywNnUtMi15UmRpYUlhRWpZRlh2REZyZmVpck1v/edit?usp=docslist_api

Comment: the `make.inc` seems ok. There is no obvious reason for this error. Try to compile `testlsame` from terminal. i.e. `gfortran  -o testlsame lsame.o lsametst.o`